# How to change debugger in QT Creator?

Tags: c++, c, qt, gdb, qt-creator

*I use QT Creator from MSYS2.*

In QT creator `Tools > Options > Build and Run > Kits` control which changes debugger is grey and I cannot change it, like in the screenshot below:
[image]

The problem is that in the kit for 32 bit software is set gdb for 64 bit software (which works incorrectly). I need to change 64 bit gdb in 32 bit kit to the gdb for 32 bit. How to do that?

Here is also screenshot from debuggers tab:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kit was installed by the installer, which explicitly set that particular debugger. Those settings can not get changed via the UI! If there is something wrong there, then the Qt installer needs to be fixed.

Of course you can clone the kit and edit the cloned kit to your liking.

If you feel like wielding your text editor, then you can of course also change the settings that the installer wrote for Creator. They are stored in a file called profiles.xml somewhere in the "share" folder of your Qt Creator installation.

Comment: Tested kit cloning and it solves the problem. Also submitted issue ticket in MSYS2 MinGW packages.